# Problems to visualize all the sides of a mesh using Three.js and Fresnel Shader

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

I am making my first steps playing with Three.js and coding with JavaScript. And since some months ago I am experimenting with Shaders and Shader Materials.

The thing is that I loaded a mesh with a Fresnel material. I can see perfectly the material in the surface, but I can't see at the inside of the mesh when I turn it : http://codepen.io/gnazoa/pen/WrLJay

I tried to make a second material and put it under the shader material. But is not the best solution, sometimes, when I load the browser, it doesn't work correctly: http://codepen.io/gnazoa/pen/rxovKb

Do you have a suggestion? Is there a way to see all the sides of the mesh using the Fresnel Shader?

Here I let the code of the shaders that I am using:

```
    <script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

    uniform float fresnelBias;
    uniform float fresnelScale;
    uniform float fresnelPower;

    varying float vReflectionFactor;
    varying vec3 vReflect;

    void main() {
      vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
      vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

      vec3 worldNormal = normalize( mat3( modelMatrix[0].xyz, modelMatrix[1].xyz, modelMatrix[2].xyz ) * normal );

      vec3 I = worldPosition.xyz - cameraPosition;

      vReflect = reflect( I, worldNormal );
      vReflectionFactor = fresnelBias + fresnelScale * pow( 1.0 + dot( normalize( I ), worldNormal ), fresnelPower );

      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

    }
      </script>

      <script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

    uniform vec3 color;
    uniform samplerCube envMap;

    varying vec3 vReflect;
    varying float vReflectionFactor;

    void main() {
      vec4 envColor = textureCube( envMap, vec3( -vReflect.x, vReflect.yz ) );
      gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(color, envColor.xyz, vec3(clamp( vReflectionFactor, 0.0, 1.0 ))), 1.0);
    }
    </script>
```

**EDIT:**

I already found the answer in the manual, it was so simple like write `side: THREE.DoubleSide`, in the material to see all the sides of the mesh.

But now I am trying to search why my mesh is not black in the inside if my color uniform is black.

Do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inside material is so highly glossy that it reflects the white over and over again. You don't see black because of this infinite reflection of white.

The easiest solution to this is setting a different inside and outside material. Your highly glossy black on the outside and a non reflective black on the inside. I tested it and it works quite well:

```
outsideMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    side: THREE.FrontSide,
    uniforms : uniforms,
    vertexShader : vertexShader,
    fragmentShader : fragmentShader,
    wireframe: false
});
insideMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    side: THREE.BackSide,
    color: 0x000000
});

var loader = new THREE.BinaryLoader();
loader.load( "http://threejs.org/examples/obj/walt/WaltHead_bin.js", function ( geometry ) {

    geometry.scale( 7, 7, 7 );

    blackObject = new THREE.Object3D();

    inside = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, insideMaterial );
    outside = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, outsideMaterial );

    blackObject.add( inside );
    blackObject.add( outside );
    scene.add( blackObject );

});
```